# Flutter - prevent user from putting app on background and prevent to open other tabs on flutter web

Tags: flutter, security, dart, web, lifecycle

I am trying to make an online examination app and for security I want to prevent the user from putting the app on background only when giving exam, like show warning or count how many time user has put the app on background.
Also on flutter web as we see on different examination sites, i want to prevent the user from going to any other tab.
How to get the desired result?